# Kentico/ASP.NET ResponseRedirect still keeps initial URL

Tags: asp.net, kentico

I have my web.config setup as follows:

```
<customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" redirectMode="ResponseRedirect" defaultRedirect="~/SpecialPages/PageNotFound.aspx">
      <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/SpecialPages/PageNotFound.aspx" responseMode="Redirect"/>
</customErrors>
```

But when a user goes to mysite.com/gibberish, my 404 page shows up, but the url stays as mysite.com/gibberish, but I want it to say mysite.com/SpecialPages/PageNotFound. Is there somethng else I am missing?

I'm using Kentico10 CMS if that makes any difference but have been following their instructions too. Seems like I'm missing something server side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anybody is reading I got an answer from kentico themselves:

> This behavior is correct from SEO point of view. Previously we had the
>   behavior you wanted but it was really bad for SEO to do a redirection
>   so it was changed and just the 404 status code is returned and the URL
>   is the same.  If you want to change this behavior, you can create
>   custom event handler and in the request end event check the status
>   code and if it is 404, do a redirection - but this can harm your SEO
>   rankings.

https://docs.kentico.com/k11/custom-development/handling-global-events/reference-global-system-events#Reference-Globalsystemevents-RequestEvents

Answer (score 1):

Have you specified `Page not found` in Kentico? If so, remove that configuration beacuse you don't want Kentico to handle error for you and then your custom errors in web.config should work as you set them up as in any other project.

Comment: Thanks Enn, I'm at least on the right track now. Just trying to get it to the page i want now instead of the IIS error page!

Comment: I would look at Kentico documentation and actually restore it back to Kentico's error handler, then in Settings you can set the 404 page.

https://docs.kentico.com/k11/securing-websites/developing-secure-websites/handling-error-messages-securely/creating-custom-error-handling-pages

Comment: That is what he did in the first place and it works, but it doesn't redirect to URL